# Implementing signal processing techniques for consistent RSSI signal reception

Tags: continuous-signals, modulation, kalman-filters, signal-power, frequency-modulation

I've tried to optimize the LoRa setup using Arduino IDE libraries to ensure accurate or acceptable RSSI measurements and for distance estimation between multiple nodes and a master in an outdoor environment using those WiFi LoRa 32 V3 modules that operate within the frequency range of 433MHz ~ 510MHz with SX1262.

How do I implement signal processing techniques for consistent signal reception to optimize RSSI to minimal variation as a drone approaches different distances from nodes in outdoor localization using those WiFi LoRa 32 V3 modules spaced 400m apart?

Expectation: To ensure minimal variation in RSSI when the drone moves together with the master (y) approaches different distances from each node (x1, x2, x3) in the trilateration layout, as if under ideal outdoor conditions.

Comment: This is an interesting project for a research paper after a gew months of thought and experiments, but ill-posed for an short answer in a web forum.  You want to.make statistical quantities consistent without defining what consistent means in this context.  Ideal outdoor conditions in VHF/UHF is ill-defined as well, as you getbquite a bit of variation between desert/dry regions and water soaked ground.  You also imply consistency independent of flight path, which is impossible.

Comment: Also for most hardware RSSI is not meaningful until you have synchronized to the incoming signal.  If you lose lock on the received signal, RSSI values emitted from the hardware are just random garbage, so that cannot be made consistent when unlocked.

Comment: plus, LoRA is kind of a worst-case choice: Legally restricted to a very limited duty cycle, small integrated modules with completely unspecified antenna patters, typically transmit power highly dependent on supply voltage and hence dependent on battery state and lift in a drone.

Comment: @AndyWalls You're right. What "consistency" meant in the context is to find RSSI in a corrective range at every specific of known distance (e.g. 0-400m) and then essentially to achieve "close" distance estimation. As you pointed out, outdoor environments can vary significantly, and where it has been tested only at dorm corridor in 0-10m and will be further tested in the farming places, which are to meet the needs of most applications.

Comment: @AndyWalls Assuming consistent RSSI measurements independent of the drone's flight path is indeed unrealistic, in which I'm yet to be investigated, since the stabilization in accuracy data of the RSSI and distance measurements have not yet been completed.  The formula that was applied as,


`float calculateDistance(int16_t rssi) {
    // Calibrated RSSI value at 1 meter (negative)
    float calibrated_rssi = -31;
    // Calculate distance based on average RSSI using calibrated RSSI at 1 meter
    float distance = (calibrated_rssi - rssi) / 20.0;
    return pow(10.0, distance);}`

Comment: @AndyWalls Particularly at larger distances, the estimated distance shows dramatic changes and inconsistencies as the RSSI values decrease. For example, the distance estimation goes from 2 meters at RSSI -37 to 3 meters at RSSI -41, 4 meters at RSSI -42, 5 meters at RSSI -45, and then remains static from 6 meters to 11 meters for every -1 RSSI decrease until 20 meters (RSSI -57). When estimating distances up to 400 meters, the reported RSSI value is as low as -83, which raises concerns about the sensitivity limits of the LoRa modules and the reliability of the signal at such low RSSI values.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yeah, you've excellent point about LoRa spec. The main problem I'm now facing is the inconsistency and potential inaccuracy of the distance estimation based on RSSI values, obviously at larger distances, which could significantly impact the overall localization performance of the system.

Comment: Thank you for sharing those insightful comments and highlighting the limitations of the question I had initially attempted to address. Given these issues, how can I further refine and optimize the RSSI-to-distance mapping function or model, ensuring consistent and accurate distance estimation across the entire range of distances involved in this outdoor localization setup?

Comment: Additionally, how can I effectively handle situations where the RSSI values become too low or unreliable due to the sensitivity limits of the LoRa modules or weak signal conditions?

Comment: at larger distances is when an RSSI estimate for a microwave frequency is still the most useful, @Ausen , because there at least the fading channel is more likely to be well-modelled as Rician. At close range, you get constructively interfering multipath components that are not direct, you can completely forget about working based on RSSI. And again, the duty cycle is an **extremely** problematic limitation, because it makes all tracking, position filtering attempts futile. So, if you think the further range is problematic, forget about working on the close end. And base your attempts

Comment: … on an actual *model* before you start going for real-world transmission. And I'd recommend that in your model you first start with a transmitter that transmits all the time, so that you can get an RSSI estimate every couple milliseconds. Then you apply uncertainty to the RSSI as you see it in a real observation for a given distance. If you can then start seeing consistent means, you could do something like a Kalman filter for tracking your position in the model. If that works, you could go on reducing the duty cycle in the model until the filter stops working and see whether you can achieve

Comment: … that with your LoRa system's legal duty cycle. I don't believe you can! If it doesn't even work in simulation, chances are it won't work in real life.